# USB WiFi dongle device that can emulate a virtual mass storage device for a home video player

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, storage

Is there a USB WiFi dongle device that can:

- Emulate a virtual mass storage device for a home video player
- But in fact shows the files from a network-shared folder?

Comment: Could you describe why you want to do this?

Comment: I have home video and photo files on my PC in shared folders. I have TV that can play video and photo from USB stick. So I want some device that will be recognized by TV as usual mass storage device, but in fact that will emulate virtual mass storage that consists of the files from shared network folder.

Comment: May be related: https://superuser.com/questions/215466/make-nas-appear-as-a-usb-drive/1613829#1613829

Answer (score 5):

*[IGRS Linksee USB 2.0 802.11g WiFi Wireless Remote Mass Storage Dongle](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/igrs-linksee-usb-2-0-802-11g-wifi-wireless-remote-mass-storage-dongle-36387)* also seems to achieve what you are after. Unfortunately, I have not yet seen a solution that is platform independent.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this.  Believe it's what you might be after:

[The Infinite USB Memory (IUM) Drive](http://infinitec.com/ium-drive/features/) by Infinitec.