# Network drive to usb bridge

Tags: network-shares, usb-storage, cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a USB WiFi dongle device that can emulate virtual mass storage device for home video player?](https://superuser.com/questions/181855/what-is-a-usb-wifi-dongle-device-that-can-emulate-virtual-mass-storage-device-for)

Sorry this is kinda of an oldball question

Is there any device that I could configure (wireless or wired (prefer wireless) to a network drive on my home server. and have it display the contents to another device (roku) as a usb hard drive

I suspect not but I'm not even sure what to call/google this thing so I thought I would ask the bright folks here.

Comment: I'm not quite clear from your wording what you're meaning here...  Do you mean that you are looking for a device that you can plug a USB drive into and have it share that drive out through the network for you?

Comment: the opposite. I want to put stuff on a shared folder on my computer. and the device (which only accepts usb thumb drives) to be able to read whats there.

Comment: Interesting... so you're looking for a wireless CIFS client that emulates a USB Mass Storage Device...  Never heard of one, but there's no reason why it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Actually, I can think of one thing making it very hard - USB MSD is a block-level protocol - CIFS is file level.  You'd need a custom server on your computer sharing a block device image, and some way to put files into that image.

Comment: yes im looking for the opposite of this http://www.eye.fi/ to usb. This is for my roku media player that for some damn fool reason only takes usb but won't connect to any of my shared drives over the intranet.

Comment: Question isn't too odd, it's been asked before. :)