# How to share a folder as an USB mass storage device (from a raspberry pi)

Tags: linux, usb, usb-storage, raspberry-pi

I'd like to do something quite simple ... in my mind.

I've got an "old" photo frame with an usb port and SD card slot (but without networking) that I would like to keep in sync with my NAS "Photo folder"

Since I'm looking forward to buy a PI, I'd like to know how I could achieve this ... in a cheap way ($ and computing power).

My main guess would be to connect both on USB.

Looking at other answers I found [Serve up PC hard drive as USB mass storage](https://superuser.com/questions/41841/serve-up-pc-hard-drive-as-usb-mass-storage) and [USB WiFi dongle device that can emulate a virtual mass storage device for a home video player](https://superuser.com/questions/181855/what-is-a-usb-wifi-dongle-device-that-can-emulate-virtual-mass-storage-device-fo) and on the PI board itself [Emulate USB mass storage device](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4938)

So from what I found so far I have two options : an [Host-to-Host USB cable](http://www.datapro.net/products/usb-2-0-host-to-host-cable.html)  or a [Wifi-to-USB adapter](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/igrs-linksee-usb-2-0-802-11g-wifi-wireless-remote-mass-storage-dongle-36387) (Both as expensive as the PI itself)

The problem is that both device are Windows only and neither seem to allow to select a specific folder to share.

Getting back to my goal, does any of you have an idea on how to to connect both on USB ?

Bonus question : is there a way to do this multiple times on the same "server" to connect different folders to differents clients (other frames/radios/...) ?

Thanks for the time spent reading my (long) question !

Comment: @MizukiOshiro I will but, from what I found yet, this won't be possible due to the USB specification design. I posted this question just in case I missed something

Comment: Some photo frames have a "second monitor" feature, that allows pushing JPEG encoded frames from the PC to the photo frame trough it's slave port. I use this feature to display RRDTool-generated graphs for my server monitoring. Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OINZfcV7EQ0

Comment: The new IO board shipped with Compute Module Development Kit seems to have USB slave connector... how can one get it working?

Comment: I know this is old, but it's easy nowadays: https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: I also know that this is quite old, but may still be up to date. This could be a solution: https://superuser.com/questions/215466/make-nas-appear-as-a-usb-drive/1613829#1613829.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically USB protocol requires one device to act as a Master, and others as Slaves. Master-master connections are not supported. Master devices typically have A-type connectors: computers, photo frames that support external USB media, etc. Slaves are your typical USB sticks, mice, etc. Master supplies power to slave over USB bus.

To cloud the water, [USB OTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) specification allows devices that support it to behave *both* as a master and as a slave (some Android phones, etc.).

Your photo frame is a master device, you need your Raspberry Pi acting as a slave. As far as I know, it is rather tricky, if possible at all: As a computer, Raspberry Pi supports USB master mode, but apparently USB slave mode also should be possible on *some* devices. Quoting the [forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4938) you mentioned in your question:

> The model B has a built in 2 port USB hub, which does not know how to act as a USB device. The model A directly connects the processor USB interface, which can be configured either as a USB device or USB host.
>
> Obviously, that won't work until people have Model A's to develop on, and someone has the talent, the time, the inclination, and the documentation, to write the device driver.
>
> Bit-banging a slow speed USB device over GPIO should be possible on the model B.

This all will require some very significant hacking, many hours of programming/debugging time. In my opinion, waste of time.

**My suggestion:** Throw out your photo frame, get some second-hand/cheap small LCD display, connect it to your Raspberry Pi and use it as a photo frame. Much easier, faster, etc.

Comment: Or just interface the existing frame display via the LCD or GPIO connectors.

Comment: From my experience, interfacing LCDs via LVDS is very far from trivial.

Comment: Well anyway, both of you seem to hold the good solution to my question : don't waste time with the USB connector :)

Comment: The new IO board shipped with Compute Module Development Kit seems to have USB slave connector... how can one get it working?